# How to draw route path with available lat long in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to draw a route path in my mobile App. Everything is working fine only route is not coming properly as per roads here is my code ..

```
 private void formRoadMapUrl(String tempLatLng) {
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder(ServerConnector.GOOGLE_ROAD_MAP_API + tempLatLng);
    urlString.append("&interpolate=true&key=" + AppConfigurationSetting.GOOGLE_ROAD_MAP_API);
    requestToServer(urlString);
}
```

here I am sending my lat long to Google ..

```
private void locationTrackPolyline(String output) {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);
        if (obj.has("snappedPoints")) {
            mResultOfGoogleRoadMapAPI++;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String result   = obj.getString("snappedPoints");

            Type type = new TypeToken<List<GoogleRoadMap>>(){}.getType();
            List<GoogleRoadMap> batchArrayModel = gson.fromJson(result, type);
            Integer batchListSize = batchArrayModel.size();

            ArrayList<LatLng> polylines = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            for (GoogleRoadMap batchObj: batchArrayModel) {
                LatLng polyline = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(batchObj.getLocation().getLatitude()),
                        Double.valueOf(batchObj.getLocation().getLongitude()));
                polylines.add(polyline);

                // TODO : animation data passing is google map
                addMarkerToMap(polyline);
            }

            // Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the mMap.
            LatLng lat = polylines.get(0);

            Integer getLength = polylines.size();
            LatLng endPoints = polylines.get(getLength - 1);

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lat, 17));
            if(mResultOfGoogleRoadMapAPI == 1) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_green100))
                        .title("Start Point")
                        .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                        .position(lat));
            }
            mAnimatedPolyline.addAll(polylines);
            if(mIterationOfGoogleRoadMapAPI == mResultOfGoogleRoadMapAPI) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_red100))
                        .title("End Point")
                        .position(endPoints));

                animator.startAnimation(true);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here I am showing path as per lat long I am getting from google.

Comment: Where is your code? Need a [MCVE]. See [Ask].

Comment: If u want to draw a line(route) u have to use google map Polyline refer this link https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

Comment: @T.Heron  now I put my code my map is working fine only problem is its not showing proper path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Please add below code 

LatLng mLatLng = new LatLng(23.2156, 72.6569);
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatLng, 10);
googlemap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);


googlemap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(lat,lng), new LatLng(23.2156, 72.6369)).width(10).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin));
markerOptions.title(“start");
googlemap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(new LatLng(23.2156, 72.6569)));

MarkerOptions markerOptionsDest = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin));
markerOptionsDest.title(“end");
googlemap.addMarker(markerOptionsDest.position(new LatLng(23.2156, 72.6369)));
```